# Can DNS requests (such as txt records) be used to serve .css & .js files?

Tags: http, dns, browserify

(*This question is very odd, I'll admit.  It is essentially a "what if" sort of question, not one I need for any project.  I would appreciate if you please correct any assumptions I make below which are not true--I'm no network engineer that's for sure!*)

**Could a DNS txt records (or a new record) be used to cache entire .css/.js files for use in web browsing?**

I suspect the simplest way to do this (if it is even possible) is to use browserify & small DNS client to 'dig' a customized node.js DNS server which has been trained to reply with entire static files (.css, .js).  A sample request might be to:  jquery.min.js.example.com where the txt record reponse would be the entire contents of jquery.min.js.  It could even be a partial hash like 7fba88.js.example.com, so the result file can be verified to come from 'unpoisoned' DNS cache, running a javascript hash on the reply in the browser.

I suspect DNS protocol may be both faster (less overhead, UPD vs TCP) than HTTP protocol and also may provide better forms of caching.  DNS txt requests (in 255 byte chunks...) may be able to be cached on your localhost to use for any website you visit--and any web browser--and quite often is also cached by your ISP.

A HTTP request also has caching, but it's not as good.  If a .css file is the same as what has already been downloaded to your browser, the browser still needs to connect to HTTP d (or a CDN like CloudFlare.com) to be given a 304 response. (Let's ignore offline cache-manifest please.)  Additionally, if you open a new tab in your browser, that new tab is going to request those static files all over again for the same site.

I imagine many ISP server administrators would be quite annoyed to see their DNS cache filled up with static files.  I don't know what they'd do in that case, perhaps they'd disallow cache for your domain, which would not be good.

Any thoughts?

Answer to @Joe: In this hypothetical scenario a DNS client, maybe browserify and [this module or similar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/native-dns/), would run in head-tag and pull the rest of the static content before the body-tag is displayed.  It wouldn't be too different than a websocket connection, because it would run inside a web page.

Comment: How would this actually help in the context of an HTTP request?  What's making the DNS requests for this content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with this approach is that the browser cannot send UDP packets.

See here for an article discussing the DNS TXT record potential vulnerability as you describe: [DNS TXT records represent vulnerability for caching DNS servers](http://qbit.cc/dns-txt-records-represent-vulnerability-for-caching-dns-servers/). As mentioned in the article, system administrators and public DNS server administrators may disable caching altogether of TXT records, which would prevent this being used as an effective caching mechanism.

[native-dns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/native-dns/) does not make the browser send DNS requests itself. A HTTP request is sent by the browser to the [Node.js DNS server module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/native-dns/) which will process the DNS request on the server and send the reply to the browser. So you'd still need to return a `HTTP 200` or `304` response to the browser, and the latter would take more work as you'd have to implement your own server side caching mechanism to determine whether the file had changed.

Comment: A `TXT` record is _not_ limited to 255 chars - the `RDLENGTH` field is 16 bits long, allowing up to 64k, less whatever else is in the packet.

Comment: Oh, and that first article is way out of date.  `TXT` didn't get deprecated - in fact `SPF` did because it was decided that the installed base of SPF clients was too large for there to ever be an effective migration from `TXT` to `SPF`.

Comment: I should clarify that - the individual strings in a `TXT` RR _are_ limited to 255 chars, because they use `<length byte><data>` format, but you can have lots of those in one resource record and they should be concatenated.

Comment: @Alnitak: Yes, that is what I understood after you corrected my initial misunderstanding. The code in the browser would have to correctly assemble these into the actual resource content (soft of a moot point since there is no mechanism to directly receive them).